# How to convert row data to column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, shared-libraries

I have a table Test with 2 column Job_name and Status contains below data,

```
Job_Name     status
------------------------
a            failed
b            completed
c            waiting
d            failed
```

I want output like below,

```
col1    col2        col3       col4
--------------------------------------
a        b          c          d
failed  completed   waiting    failed
```

I tried using pivot , but not able to achieve the exact output .
Please let me know , how can I proceed with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include your query?  Also, does your actual data have more than 4 job types, and does the same job type occur more than once?

Comment: @Tim biegeleisen , i have more than 200 Job types all unique values.

Comment: Then you might want to handle this with dynamic SQL.  Beyond my pay grade, but poke around on SO and you will find some help.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Dynamic Pivot

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..##Tmp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##Tmp
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max) = ''
    DECLARE @hdrs nvarchar(max) = ''
    DECLARE @Cols1 nvarchar(max) = ''

    ; WITH T (JOb_Name , Status) as
        (
        SELECT 'a' ,'failed'
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'b' ,'completed'
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'c' ,'waiting'
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'd' , 'failed'
        )

    SELECT * 
    INTO ##Tmp 
    FROM t

    SELECT @hdrs += ','+QUOTENAME(JOb_Name) + ' AS Col_'+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER () OVER(ORDER BY job_Name) AS nvarchar(5))
    FROM ##Tmp 
    ORDER BY JOb_Name
    SET @hdrs = STUFF(@hdrs,1,1,'')

    SELECT @cols += ','+QUOTENAME(JOb_Name)
    FROM ##Tmp
    ORDER BY JOb_Name
    SET @cols = STUFF(@Cols ,1,1,'')

    SELECT @Cols1 += ','+QUOTENAME(Cols)
        FROM
        (
        SELECT Job_Name, 'Col_' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER () OVER(ORDER BY job_Name) AS nvarchar(5)) Cols
        FROM ##Tmp
        ) X 

    SET @Cols1 = STUFF (@cols1,1,1,'')

    SET @sql = 
    '
    SELECT *
    FROM 
        (
                SELECT Job_Name, ''Col_'' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER () OVER(ORDER BY job_Name) AS nvarchar(5)) Cols
                FROM ##Tmp
        ) x
        PIVOT (
            MAX(Job_Name) FOR Cols IN ('+@cols1+')
            ) P
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '+@hdrs+' 
    FROM ##Tmp 
        PIVOT (
            MAX(Status) FOR Job_Name IN ('+@cols+')
            ) P
    '
    exec sp_executesql @sql
    DROP TABLE ##Tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @x table (Job_Name char(1), [status] varchar(15))
insert into @x values
('a','failed'),
('b','completed'),
('c','waiting'),
('d','failed')

select * from
(
    select 'col' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() over (order by job_name) as varchar(2)) [colName],
           [status]
    from @x
) as [toPivot]
pivot
(
    max([status])
    for
    colName in([col1],[col2],[col3],[col4])
) as [p1]

union all

select * from
(
    select 'col' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() over (order by job_name) as varchar(2)) [colName],
           Job_Name
    from @x
) as [toPivot]
pivot
(
    max([job_name])
    for
    colName in([col1],[col2],[col3],[col4])
) as [p2]
```